# TCP communication issue

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am developping a library to communicate with a proprietary software through their remote control API, that uses TCP/IP.

It basically consists  of two different connections : the **control connection** on a TCP port and the **data connection** on another TCP port. Both are independant from each other.

I'm supposed to send commands and receive answers to these commands via the control connection, the data connection being reserved to transfer images.

It works like a charm for "small" images (up to approximately 600*500 pixels), but starting from a certain size, the connection fails in a strange way.

The thing is, I know exactly how the image data sent through TCP/IP is structured :

- Identifying string - 16 bytes
- Data size TCP (**n** + 32) - 16 bytes
- Id - 4 bytes
- Channel - 4 bytes
- Index - 4 bytes
- BPP - 4 bytes
- Data size pixels (**n**) - 4 bytes
- Pixels - **n** bytes (can be in several TCP messages but transparent)
- Repeat until all pixels have been sent

Knowing that, I developped a ReadImage() method to parse messages :

```
// These variables are created here to avoid creating new ones at each ReadImage() call, to improve speed
private byte[] readbuffer32 = new byte[32]; // Header
private byte[] readbuffer16 = new byte[16]; // Data size
private byte[] readbuffer4 = new byte[4]; // Muti-purpose (Id, Channel, Index & BPP)

private bool ReadImage(int width, int height, int? frameId, int bpp, out byte[] image)
        {
            image = null;
            int totalbytes = width * height * (bpp / 8); // Total number of bytes to be received
            int receivedbytes = 0;

            image = new byte[totalbytes]; // Whole image in 1D

            int index = 0; // Where to append incoming data in the big image array

            while (receivedbytes < totalbytes)
            {
                    // Header
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer32, 0, readbuffer32.Length, SocketFlags.None, out SocketError se);
                    string name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readbuffer32, 0, 16).Trim('\0'); // I remove the null characters (0x00)
                    int totalsize = BitConverter.ToInt32(readbuffer32, 16);

                    // Frame identifier (unused)
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer4, 0, readbuffer4.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);

                    // Channel (unused)
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer4, 0, readbuffer4.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);

                    // Pixel index (unused)
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer4, 0, readbuffer4.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);

                    // Bits Per Pixel
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer4, 0, readbuffer4.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);
                    int bppread = BitConverter.ToInt32(readbuffer4, 0);

                    // Data size
                    Socket_data.Receive(readbuffer4, 0, readbuffer4.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);
                    int datasize = BitConverter.ToInt32(readbuffer4, 0);

                    receivedbytes += datasize;

                    // Image data
                    byte[] imagedata = new byte[datasize];
                    Socket_data.Receive(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length, SocketFlags.None, out se);

                    Array.Copy(imagedata, 0, image, index, imagedata.Length); // Add read pixels into the image
                    index += imagedata.Length;

            }
        }
```

`ReadImage()` is called just after a "take an image" command was sent through the control port.

When I debugged a big image acquisition in step-by-step mode, it worked perfectly. When I restarted the exact same acquisition without any breakpoint, it failed. *(Note : I know that the software is able to handle images that big. It's a demo software, so it generates the images it sends to me)*

The error is that the `name` variable, and so the first use of `readbuffer32` (the first bytes read) do not contain the expected values. Instead, the array contains pixel values.

Wireshark confirmed that all message were sent correctly, and that they were correct.

I'm thinking it's more of a timing issue. I already added a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before each call to `ReadImage()`, but that only postponed the issue.

`System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive()` is supposed to read the number of wanted bytes unil all of them are received or a timeout is reached. But no timeout is ever reached, and no `SocketError` is ever given.

Could it be possible that `Socket.Receive()` tries to read bytes before they had time to arrive entirely, hence being filled with wrong values ?

Is there a combination of `SocketFlags` that could tell the method to "take it easy, bytes will arrive eventually" ?

Thank you.

Comment: With the stream protocol TCP, it is your job to collect received bytes until you can interpret them.

Comment: "System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive() is supposed to read the number of wanted bytes unil all of them are received or a timeout is reached" - that's not quite true. It can read less bytes (for TCP), that's why it returns a value - specifically it returns number of bytes actually read. You ignore this value everywhere, hence the problem.

Comment: You have no control over what is in the receive buffer. The communication partner may distribute the response over several packets of which some already arrived and others not.

Comment: The issue was that I didn't take into account the amount of bytes actually read. Using a `while` loop solved it. Thank you @Evk !